# Firebase Validation Details

Tags: firebase

Is there any way to get the REAL reason for a failure to save data in Firebase?  Right now, it seems that any data validation issue or security issue results in a "PERMISSION_DENIED" error.

That is not particularly useful.  Does it mean the user is not valid?  Does it mean the user doesn't have permission to write somewhere?  Does it mean that the property "accountName" must be longer than 2 characters and shorter than 500?

Permission Denied should mean the user doesn't have permission.

Surely there is a way to find out the VALIDATION failure?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you debug Firebase security rules in your account Dashboard, under the simulator tab. Begin by logging in with the same user permissions that you do on the client. You only need to include the ones that are accessed by the security rules, such as id or uid. Generally something like this:

[image: simulator auth view]

Then you can enter the payload you are attempting to write at the client and see which rules are failing:

[image: simulator write data]

You can achieve similar behavior on the client by creating a custom auth token and adding `debug: true` to the config settings. But this is [a bit more involved](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/guide/user-auth.html).

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't really help. I'm not going to debug in a test console.  More importantly, in a real app, when a user submits something invalid that I miss locally, I need the server to tell me what's wrong. Every API I've ever encountered (or created) does this.

Comment: Sorry you don't like this answer. However, this is how one finds out about security rules failures. Use the simulator or use the special auth token. There are no other options, nor is it particularly uncommon to obscure the inner security layers of an app from end users. It is, in fact, a solid security practice.

Comment: So there is no way to distinguish between a validation and permission error on the client?

Comment: This method really is only useful for very simple cases. I don't think the simulator can be used to debug multipath updates, since it only allows you to specify a single location. More advanced applications use multipath updates as a way to guarantee database integrity, and we have rules to make sure that the data in each of the paths is consistent.

Comment: @Kato Security through obscurity is not a solid security practice.

Comment: A nice platitude, but entirely different than broadcasting your security model to the world. Security rules are real security and they are enhanced by not allowing reverse engineering.